# Could not insert Student record in database.(spring 3.0.5, mybatis3.0.3, mysql)

Tags: mysql, spring

I have been trying to insert a Student record in mysql database, using spring 3 & mybatis3, but i am constantly getting following exception.

```
com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) --- The error occurred in /config/StudentMapper.xml.  
 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) --- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) --- Check the insertStudent-InlineParameterMap.  
 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) --- Check the statement (update failed).  
 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) --- Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lastName)' at line 1
```

Please Help me resolve this exception.

sqlMapConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig 
PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN"
"http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">

<sqlMapConfig>

<properties resource="/config/SqlMapConfigExample.properties"/>

<settings cacheModelsEnabled="true" enhancementEnabled="true"
    useStatementNamespaces="false" />

<transactionManager type="JDBC" commitRequired="false">
    <dataSource type="SIMPLE">
        <property name="JDBC.Driver" value="${driver}" />
        <property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL" value="${url}" />
        <property name="JDBC.Username" value="${username}" />
        <property name="JDBC.Password" value="${password}" />
        <property name="JDBC.DefaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>

    </dataSource>
</transactionManager>

<sqlMap resource="/config/StudentMapper.xml" /> 


</sqlMapConfig>
```

My StudentMapper.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>   
<!DOCTYPE sqlMap   
PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN"         "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd">

<sqlMap namespace="com.fulcrum.mappers.StudentMapper">

<resultMap id="result" class="com.fulcrum.model.Student">
    <result property="id" column="id" />
    <result property="firstName" column="firstName" />
    <result property="lastName" column="lastName" />
</resultMap>

<insert id="insertStudent" parameterClass="com.fulcrum.model.Student">
<![CDATA[
        INSERT INTO student (firstName, lastName) VALUES  (#firstName,#lastName);
    ]]>
    <selectKey  keyProperty="id" >
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id
    </selectKey>

</insert>

</sqlMap>
```

My insertStudentCode in daoimpl-

```
public void insertStudent(Student student) {
System.out.println("UserDaoImpl insertStudent()");
System.out.println("Student Name::" +student.getFirstName()+"  "+student.getLastName());



    /*New*/
    String resource = "/config/SqlMapConfig.xml";
    Reader reader;
    try {
        reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader (resource);
        SqlMapClient sqlMap =  SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(reader);
        System.out.println("SqlMap::::" +sqlMap);
    //  sqlMap.startTransaction();
        sqlMap.insert("insertStudent", student);

    //  sqlMap.commitTransaction();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

My Student Class Code-

```
package com.fulcrum.model;

public class Student {
private Long id;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

}

Comment: Is id auto-incremented value at DB side?

Comment: @erhun- yes id is auto-incremented at DB side.

Comment: @erhun- I changed my INSERT statement and i got following error-    Error parsing XML. Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMap/insert'. Cause: com.ibatis.common.beans.ProbeException: There is no READABLE property named '{firstName}' in class 'com.fulcrum.model.Student'

Comment: Can you please share the Student class code?

Comment: I have added my Student Class Code.

Comment: Please try it via INSERT INTO student (firstName, lastName) VALUES (#firstName#,#lastName#); Source tutorial http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/pdf/iBATIS-SqlMaps-2-Tutorial_en.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I looked through some mybatis samples -

Shouldn't mybatis parameters be wrapped as - (#{id}, #{username}, #{password})

https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html

Looks like the root cause of ur error from your stack trace is - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lastName)' at line 1

Comment: I tried same, but i got following error-  Error parsing XML. Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMap/insert'. Cause: com.ibatis.common.beans.ProbeException: There is no READABLE property named '{firstName}' in class 'com.fulcrum.model.Student'

Comment: your student java class has a firstname attribute right?

Comment: Yes. I have also included my Student Class above.

Comment: @AnkitNautiyal usually u get this message when the parameter doesnt match the field name in the model objet..try without the curly braces (as above) see if that helps..